# The is no procedure with the name 'gds.alpha.ml.nodeClassification.train'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

> **Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound** There is no procedure with
> the name `gds.alpha.ml.nodeClassification.train` registered for this
> database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name
> correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

I have installed Graph Data Science Library v1.4.1 , and my Neo4j Desktop is v1.4.5. The beta algorithms are working fine but for some reason the alpha algorithms are not. I'm following the Node Classification oficial tutorial from Neo4j. The original code where is the error:

```
CALL gds.alpha.ml.nodeClassification.train('marvel_model_data', {
   nodeLabels: ['Character'],
   modelName: 'xmen-model-properties',
   featureProperties: ['energy','speed','strength','durability','intelligence'],
   targetProperty: 'is_xman',
   metrics: ['F1_WEIGHTED','ACCURACY'],
   holdoutFraction: 0.2,
   validationFolds: 5,
   randomSeed: 2,
   params: [
       {penalty: 0.0625, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 0.125, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 0.25, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 0.5, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 1.0, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 2.0, maxIterations: 1000},
       {penalty: 4.0, maxIterations: 1000}
       ]
    }) YIELD modelInfo
  RETURN
  modelInfo.bestParameters AS winningModel,
  modelInfo.metrics.F1_WEIGHTED.outerTrain AS trainGraphScore,
  modelInfo.metrics.F1_WEIGHTED.test AS testGraphScore
```

Answer (score 0):

The node classification algorithm (as well as the link prediction algorithm) was provided in GDS version 1.5.  v1.4 still had the other beta algorithms that you are likely referring to.  So you will need to upgrade to that in order to make node classification work.